# Read records from one table , and write to another table. Exception occurs procedure or function has too many arguments specified?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to retrieve list of records from one table , and write to another table. I've used a simple query to retrieve the values to SqlDataReader,then load them to a DataTable. Using the DataTableReader , I am going through the entire data set which is Saved in DataTable. The problem is, while reading each and every record I am trying to insert those values to another table using a Stored Procedure.But it only insert the first row of values,and for the second row onward giving some Exception saying.*"procedure or function has too many arguments specified"*.

---

```
string ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection NewCon = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
NewCon.Open();

SqlCommand NewCmd3 = NewCon.CreateCommand();
NewCmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
NewCmd3.CommandText ="select * from dbo.Request_List where  group_no ='" +group_no+      "'";
NewCon.Close();
NewCon.Open(); 
SqlDataReader dr = (SqlDataReader)NewCmd3.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);
DataTableReader reader = new DataTableReader(dt);

NewCmd.Dispose();
NewCon.Close();
NewCon.Open();

SqlCommand NewCmdGrpReqSer = NewCon.CreateCommand();
NewCmdGrpReqSer.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
NewCmdGrpReqSer.CommandText = "Voucher_Request_Connection";
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    int request_no = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        request_no = (int)reader["request_no"];
        NewCmdGrpReqSer.Parameters.Add("@serial_no", serial_no);
        NewCmdGrpReqSer.Parameters.Add("@request_no", request_no);
        try
        {
            NewCmdGrpReqSer.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Updated");//just to check the status.tempory 
        }
        catch (Exception xcep)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(xcep.Message);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(request_no.ToString());// 
    }
    NewCmdGrpReqSer.Dispose();
    NewCon.Close();
}
```

Any Solutions ?

Comment: You should be wrapping your disposable objects with the `using` statement, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Sparky suggests, the problem is that you continue to add parameters to the insertion command.  There are several other ways in which the code could be improved, however.  These improvements would remove the need to clear the parameters and would help to make sure you don't leave disposable resources undisposed.

First - use the `using` statement for your disposable objects. This removes the need for the explicit Close (btw, only one of Close/Dispose is needed for the connection as I believe Dispose calls Close).  Second, simply create a new command for each insertion. This will prevent complex logic around resetting the parameters and, possibly, handling error states for the command.  Third, check the results of the insertion to make sure it succeeds. Fourth, explicitly catch a SqlException - you don't want to accidentally hide unexpected errors in your code.  If it's necessary to make sure all exceptions don't bubble up, consider using multiple exception handlers and "doing the right thing" for each case - say logging with different error levels or categories, aborting the entire operation rather than just this insert, etc.  Lastly, I would use better variable names. In particular, avoid appending numeric identifiers to generic variable names. This makes the code harder to understand, both for others and for yourself after you've let the code sit for awhile.

Here's my version.  Note there are several other things that I might do such as make the string literals into appropriately named constants. Introduce a strongly-typed wrapper around the ConfigurationManager object to make testing easier. Remove the underscores from the variable names and use camelCase instead. Though those are more stylistic in nature, you might want to consider them as well.

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
using (var newConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    newConnection.Open();

    using (var selectCommand = newConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        select.CommandText ="select request_no from dbo.Request_List where group_no = @groupNumber";
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("groupNumber", group_no);

        using (dataReader = (SqlDataReader)newCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.HasRows && reader.Read())
            {
                using (var insertCommand = newConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    insertCommand.CommandText = "Voucher_Request_Connection";

                    var request_no = (int)reader["request_no"];
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@serial_no", serial_no);
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@request_no", request_no);
                    try
                    {
                         if (insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                         {
                             MessageBox.Show("Connection Updated");//just to check the status.tempory 
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             MessageBox.Show("Connection was not updated " + request_no);
                         }
                    }
                    catch (SqlException xcep)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(xcep.Message);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(request_no.ToString());// 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your parameters each time...

```
while (reader.Read())
{
request_no = (int)reader["request_no"];

//  Add this line
NewCmdGrpReqSer.Parameters.Clear();

NewCmdGrpReqSer.Parameters.Add("@serial_no", serial_no);
NewCmdGrpReqSer.Parameters.Add("@request_no", request_no);
try
{
```

Comment: Even though my answer will solve the problem you reported, tvanfosson's answer is worth reading and learning from....  He makes a lot of good points and examples